# Using the roots of $ z^5=1$, or otherwise, write $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1$ as the product of two quadratic expressions with real coefficients.

Tags: calculus, roots

Using the roots of $z^5=1$, or otherwise, write $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1$ as the product of two quadratic expressions with real coefficients.
Hence find the exact value of the product $\cos(2\pi/5)\cos(4\pi/5)$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how to approach this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots of $$z^5=1$$ are $e^{2\pi ik/5}$ where $k=\pm2,\pm1,0$

The roots of $$\dfrac{z^5-1}{z-1}=0$$ are $e^{2\pi ik/5}$ where $k=\pm2,\pm1$

$$\left(z-e^{-2\cdot2\pi i/5}\right)\left(z-e^{2\cdot2\pi i/5}\right)\left(z-e^{-1\cdot2\pi i/5}\right)\left(z-e^{1\cdot2\pi i/5}\right)=0$$

Now $$\left(z-e^{-k\cdot2\pi i/5}\right)\left(z-e^{k\cdot2\pi i/5}\right)=z^2+1-2z\cos\dfrac{2k\pi}5$$

$$\implies\left(z^2+1-2z\cos\dfrac{2\pi}5\right)\left(z^2+1-2z\cos\dfrac{2\cdot2\pi}5\right)=z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yup, thanks a lot!

Comment: why did you do (z^5-1)/(z-1)?

Comment: @Moon Because $z^5 -1=(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)$

Comment: so how does us getting the roots of (z^5-1)/(z-1), affect getting the expressions. Also how is k=±2,±1,0 for e^(2πik/5)

Comment: @Moon, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers and roots of $$\dfrac{z^5-1}{z-1}=0$$ are those of $$z^5=1$$ excluding $$1=e^{2\pi\cdot0/5}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1
=(z^2+az+1)(z^2+bz+1)
$,
because that takes care
of the first and last terms.

$(z^2+az+1)(z^2+bz+1)
=z^4+z^3(a+b)+z^2(ab+2)+z(a+b)+1
$
so we need
$a+b = 1$
and
$ab+2 = 1$
or
$ab = -1$.

Since
$(z-u)(z-v)
=z^2-z(u+v)+uv
$,
$a$ and $b$
are the roots of
$z^2-(a+b)z+ab
=z^2-z-1
$.

This will give the desired factorization.